# Insert and print stationery

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying this for a few hours now, but I can't figure out how to get an image as stationery in my background in Excel 2010. In all ways it seems I just can't get it spread from the top left to bottom right corner.

Can I accomplish this with a macro, or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: sorry but I am not sure I've understood your issue. Do you mean you want to have an image that will remain static while you scroll over the worksheet? or do you want to have a background image while you print?

Comment: See my comment on chris neilsen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

See the [microsoft link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-or-remove-a-sheet-background-HP005198468.aspx?CTT=3)

To quote
*"In Excel, you can use a picture as a sheet background for display purposes only. A sheet background is not printed and is not retained in an individual worksheet or in an item that you save as a Web page. It is retained only when you publish an entire workbook as a Web page.

 Important   Because a sheet background is not printed, it cannot be used as a watermark. You can, however, mimic a watermark by inserting a graphic in a header or footer."*

Comment: I don't have to get it printed. I have a macro to save it as PDF. And the image has to cover the full A4 size (when the A4-format is selected), wich is only needed on one (A4)-page and one sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will let you choose a picture (you can already have one and adapt this code), it will resize the picture to fit the printarea and align it on the top left of the printarea:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
    Dim PicLocation As String
    Dim MyRange As Range, TargetCell As Range

    Set MyRange = Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
    Set TargetCell = MyRange.Cells(1, 1)

    PicLocation = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("C:\", "Image Files (*.jpg),*.jpg", , "Specify Image Location")

    If PicLocation <> "False" Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicLocation).Select
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Selection.ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        If .Width > .Height Then
            .Width = MyRange.Width
            If .Height > MyRange.Height Then .Height = MyRange.Height + ActiveSheet.PageSetup.HeaderMargin + ActiveSheet.PageSetup.BottomMargin
        Else
            .Height = MyRange.Height
            If .Width > MyRange.Width Then .Width = MyRange.Width + ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin + ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightMargin
        End If
        .Left = TargetCell.Left - ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin
        .Top = TargetCell.Top - ActiveSheet.PageSetup.HeaderMargin
    End With

    With Selection
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks promising, and it works. But, not as I hoped it would. My goal is to cover the WHOLE sheet. I think with 'Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)' you can't get the image outside the cells (in the blank margin)

Comment: Actually, you could resize the picture a little larger than the rangearea (change the width and the height in the code). You can also change the shifting (`.Left` and `.Top`)

Comment: Could you please give the syntax? I have no idea how to accomplish it. My VBA-knowledge is not very accurate.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a try. Yet, it won't work because you can't add any information within the margin (unless you set the margin to 0) because your printer wouldn't print within the borders (and your PDF printer will work in the same way)

Comment: But IF I set the margins to 0, there are still margins. Is there a workaround at all?